# Post file to Web Api 2.0 to save in Amazon S3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, amazon-s3

I have setup a MVC WebApi to save files to amazon S3. So when a file is posted I use a MultipartMemoryStreamProvider in order to get the file as a byte array without saving it to server and then send it to S3. I use POSTman plugin to chrome to call my endpoint and the frontend UI uses angular.js

```
if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }

        byte[] fileContent = new byte[0];
        string path = string.Empty;

        FileModel file = new FileModel();
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith( f =>
        {
            var content = provider.Contents.Single(c => c.Headers.ContentType != null);

            fileContent = content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            file.FileName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', '"', '/','\\' });
            file.FileType = content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
            file.ProjectId = id;
        });

        if (file.FileName.ValidateString(Config.FileNameRegex) == false)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File name has unsupported characters.");
        }

        int fileId = this.fileService.CreateFile(file, fileContent);
```

All is working great except that sometimes, no file comes in the request. I get an error on:

```
var content = provider.Contents.Single(...
```

coz Contents.Count is 0. I still can not figure out why. I have two video files .mp4. First .mp4 is working and for the second one it doesn't. They are the same video and I can play them all on my PC so I know they are valid and working. I don't think the API should care what file I send him or if it's a valid one. Does anyone have an Idea.

EDIT: The problem is not that I get an error, the problem is that no file is coming from the POST. But only sometimes!!!!

Comment: Go through your code and check for null before calling properties on objects then you will fix your problem.

Comment: I don't think you understand or I'm not sure what you mean. The "provider.Contents" is a collection that gets populated with the data that has been posted. And I know there is a file posted coz I send it my self. But still depending on the file (not the extension) sometimes the collection has items and sometimes it doesn't. I got the idea from here: https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-to-the-server-using-javascript-and-mvc-webapi/

Comment: The problem is not that I get an error, the problem is that no file is coming from the POST. But only sometimes!!!!

Comment: you still need need to check for null in your code regardless because i dont see any.

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem. Code above works, but the problem was request was too big. I had to edit the Web.config maxRequestLength and the maxAllowedContentLength

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="13107200" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```